# Using php with two different contact forms on a website

Tags: php

I have two contacts forms on my website and have set up some php to send the data to a specified email address. I want to use the same php on both forms which are on different web pages. It is working on one page but not the other. I haven't used php before so am wondering if I am missing something glaring obvious, any help much appreciated. Here is my php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['emailaddress'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $msg=$_POST['message'];

        $to='example@hotmail.com';
        $subject='Inquiry from website';
        $message=   "Name: ".$name."\n".
                    "Phone number: ".$phone."\n".
                    "Email address: ".$email."\n".
                    "The following inquiry has been made :"."\n\n".$msg;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
            echo "<h1>Message sent successfully. Thank you"." ".$name.", we will contact you as soon as possible.</h1>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have added my html into the post:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" required class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="emailaddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="phone" required class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="form-control" placeholder="Message"
                  cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-5" value="Send Message">
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: not working ? If you are not more specific, surely we can't (and don't want to) help. What's the problem ? No mail sent ? Have you an error in the server error log ?

Comment: by the way, you should include a `From:` header with the appropriate sending email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your html

please send your html form

Comment: I have added in the html.

Comment: your php file name is mail.php is that correct?

action is important please add mail.php into action property
@norniron

Comment: I have it in: <form action="mail.php" method="POST">

Comment: each form is in separated file?
if you answer is yes are you include mail.php into both file?

Comment: Yes, both forms are in separate files and I have included <form action="mail.php" method="POST"> in both.

Comment: are you using follow snippet?
include_once 'mail.php';